# How to add leading zeros in MatLab (number formatting)?

Tags: matlab

Here is a very specific example

```
>> S = num2str(12345,'%6.0e')
S =
1e+04
```

and that's just great since I want only my first digit and an exponential notation. However I also want to add leading zeros to the exponent in order to fill the width, but I cannot quite find the way to get the following...

```
1e+004
```

Meanwhile it's very straighforward to pad the significant digits with leading zeros

```
>> S = num2str(12345,'%06.0e')
S =
01e+04
```

So is there an appropriate formatting for what I want? Or a trick to accomplish it quickly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exponent is always a zero-padded two-digit value. To add, say, two zeros you can use

```
regexprep(num2str(12345, '%6.0e'), '\+', '\+00')
```

and achieve

```
ans =
1e+0004
```

Edit: To cover negative exponents you may use

```
regexprep(num2str(0.12345, '%6.0e'), '(\+|\-)', '$100')
```

to achieve

```
ans =
1e-0001
```

And, to cover three-digit exponents

```
regexprep(num2str(1e-100, '%6.0e'), '(\+|\-)(\d{2,3})$', {'$10$2', '$10$2'})

ans =
1e-0100

regexprep(num2str(1e-10, '%6.0e'), '(\+|\-)(\d{2,3})$', {'$10$2', '$10$2'})

ans =
1e-0010
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you have to edit, what you say you want is wat you get :D

however, if I understood correctly what you are looking for, this function will help you

```
function printX(x, digits)
    format = sprintf('\t%%.%de', digits - 1);
    strcat(inputname(1), ' = ', sprintf(format, x))
end
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Now it's edited. Apparently your function allows to have precision provided as an argument. However my precision is always the same, I just want to pad some zeros i.e. e+001, e+002, e+003 or e+0001, e+0002, e+0003 (depending on the width) instead of always e+01, e+02, e+03.